# React - New Context API not working with Class.contextType, but works with Context.Consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm trying out the new context API using a HOC that returns a wrapped component. It doesn't work when I use the `Class.contextType = Context` approach:

```
return function myHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  class HOC extends React.Component {
    // static contextType = MyContext;

    render() {
      console.log(this.context);  // HERE, this logs `{}`

      // ..do stuff
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }
  HOC.contextType = MyContext;

  return HOC;
};
```

However, I made the same code but using `<MyContext.Consumer>` and it worked fine:

```
return function myHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  const HOC = (props) => (
    <MyContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => {
        console.log(context);  // HERE, correct values

        return <WrappedComponent {...props} /> 
      }}
    </MyContext.Consumer>
  );

  return HOC;
};
```

Am I not seeing something here?

Comment: For anyone else like me searching for the difference between Class.contextType and Context.Consumer that got redirected to this question, here's an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54283509/react-context-context-consumer-vs-class-contexttype/54283511#54283511

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that even though I updated my react-scripts to `2.0`, I had to update react to `16.6` (previously on 16.3) on my own.

I was under the impression react-scripts would also handle the react version. My bad, got confused there.

Comment: I'm still getting {} for console.log(this.context). Updated the react-scripts version and react version. Can you help me with it