# React Context - Context.Consumer vs Class.contextType

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am learning about the somewhat newly introduced React.Context API, but I've noticed some inconsistencies on it's consumption across examples. Some use the original **Context.Consumer** HOC method, while some (including the React Docs) use the static **Class.contextType** method.

What's the difference and why the inconsistency?

Comment: Documented in Q&A format as I couldn't find a single satisfactory concise search result when googling things question as of today.

Answer (score 19):

Turns out that the **static Class.contextType** was [newly introduced on React v16.6.0](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#static-contexttype), as the **Context.Consumer** method proved problematic on class components. Also, there does seem to be one **major difference** between using both, and it's that the static Class.Context only allows you to subscribe to a single context.

The good news is that both of them seem to reliably listen of Context changes which means if you only have a single Context API, then both are good enough.